# For Loop in Javascript (document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript

I have a little Javascript problem. Instead of using this:

```
document.getElementById("hoverinv1").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv2").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv3").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv4").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv5").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv6").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv7").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv8").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv9").style.display = "";
document.getElementById("hoverinv10").style.display = "";
```

I wanted to use this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
    document.getElementById("hoverinv" + x).style.display="";
}
```

To display again everything. Well, it does nothing and I have no idea whats the problem.

Comment: give your elements a class instead?

Comment: `x` should start from `1` not `0`

Comment: Look at the console.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably throwing an error on the first iteration because hoverinv0 does not exist.  You want

```
for (var x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
  document.getElementById("hoverinv" + x).style.display="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do it simply in CSS:**

```
[id^=hoverinv] {
  display: block; /* or any other needed display value */
}
```

**Your issue:** by inspecting your JS in **Console** you can clearly see that it breaks while fetching your `hoverinv0` ID element (*does not exists*).

**What you can:**

assign a class `class="hoverinv"` to all your element and go for:

```
var hoverInv = document.getElementsByClassName("hoverinv");
for (var i=0; i<hoverInv.length; i++){
     hoverInv[i].style.display = "";
}
```

or using

```
var hoverInv = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=hoverinv]");
for (var i=0; i<hoverInv.length; i++){
     hoverInv[i].style.display = "";
}
```

or something **you might go fix all over again as soon you change the number of elements**:

```
for(var i=1; i<11; i++){
   document.getElementById("hoverinv"+ i).style.display = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code starts with `"hoverinv1"` and in your loop you start with `"hoverinv0"`.

Probably, it is not finding the element, returning `undefined` and then your script crashes when you try to access `style` property.

Check the browser's console, it should emit an error or something.