# HTML doesn't continue paragraph after script (Code)

Tags: javascript, html

My code currently works how it should other than herb2 and herb3 not showing up or using the randomizer. I'm not very experienced with coding and have no idea how to make this work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <br>
    <p>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</p>
    <p>D1X (MOD1)</p>
    <p>
    EPN419<br>
        Tesla 1 (left): <span id="demo1"></span><br>
        Tesla 1 (right): <span id="demo2"></span><br>
        Tesla 2: <span id="demo3"></span><br>
        Tesla 3: <span id="demo4"></span><br>
    </p>

    <script>
        for (var x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
            document.getElementById("demo" + x).innerHTML =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2 + '0%';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: You're not closing the `a` elements. `</a>`

Comment: `id` should be unique within the document, and `getElementById` will return the first one it finds, so there’s no expectation here that all three elements would be modified.

Comment: You're not closing the a tag and the id must be unique. If you want to get various elements use a class. In the script, to randomizer all elements with the same class (not id), use the querySelectorAll(".xxxx") and inside a forEach loop, you call the innerHTML.

Comment: put code in the question @ZaHecc

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a node list - that doesn't have `innerHTML` ... also the selector `"demo"` would select all `<demo>` elements - which of course is made up

Comment: I'm sure this would be all super helpful if I knew how to apply anything you guys say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your script runs, it finds only one demo id.

Here's code that is using 3 separate IDs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <br>
    <p>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</p>
    <p>Herbs Availability</p>
    <p>
        Herb1 - <a id="demo"></a>
        Herb2 - <a id="demo1"></a>
        Herb3 - <a id="demo2"></a>
    </p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2 + '0%';
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2 + '0%';
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2 + '0%';
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Your next learning step could be for loops to avoid repetition.

Example using a for loop (adjusted ID to demo1 to demo3), see [For Loop in Javascript (document.getElementById)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847366/for-loop-in-javascript-document-getelementbyid)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <br>
    <p>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</p>
    <p>Herbs Availability</p>
    <p>
        Herb1 - <a id="demo1"></a>
        Herb2 - <a id="demo2"></a>
        Herb3 - <a id="demo3"></a>
    </p>

    <script>
        for (var x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
            document.getElementById("demo" + x).innerHTML =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2 + '0%';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: How would this look if a loop was used?

Comment: See updated post

Comment: Out of interest: Why do you use `<a>` instead of `<p>` or `<span>`?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing tbh, I just was trying to use something that wasn't going to force a line break

Comment: The loop one is more what I'm looking for. I added `<br>` after each `</a>` to make a new line after each %. I tried to add more herbs but it didn't create a percent for them. How could I add more to this?

Comment: For 5 elements you need to increase the 4 in the loop by one. Learn more about for loops here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp - you can also add an ID to the surrounding `<p>` tag and loop through the number of children, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094230/how-do-i-loop-through-children-objects-in-javascript